# Classic ASP: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: sql, asp-classic

In the classic ASP site I am working on, I need to get the id of the current site owner to export an email list in Excel to that user. I get the error mentioned in the subject on my SQL line. I can't get ID any way I try. When I put a number in that corresponds to an ID in the database, data is pulled just fine. I have no idea what to put after `WHERE ID =` to make this work

```
<%
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
SQL = "SELECT ID, storeNumber, siteOwner FROM OrderOwners WHERE ID = " & rs("ID")
rs.Open SQL, conn, AdOpenStatic, AdLockPessimistic
If NOT rs.EOF then
    %>
        <textbox value="<% = rs("ID") %>"><% = rs("storeNumber") & " - " & rs("siteOwner") %></textbox>
    <%
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
%>
```

I'm not really sure what to do because I don't usually work in classic asp and this site was written a long, long time ago.

When I use that SQL statement in SQL Server and replace rs("ID") with '1', the statement runs just fine. Can someone help me please? I can't find anything that has seemed to help.

UPDATED SQL TO

```
    SQL = "SELECT ID, storeNumber, siteOwner FROM OrderOwners WHERE ID = ?
```

but now I have the error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
```

on line 19 which is

```
rs.Open SQL, conn, AdOpenStatic, AdLockPessimistic
```

Comment: Are you sure you are posting all the code as in your example nothing is mentioned about COUNT

Comment: @DevCentral That confused me too. I have no idea where `COUNT` came from. There are 4 other files being included here so I will have to check everywhere else to see what is being counted.

Comment: Has this been resolved now, or do you still need help?

Comment: Well it turns out that the `ID` I was trying to get was actually called siteOwnerID and had that value being pulled on a completely different page. I didn't see it because it is being included on a page that is included on this page. Thanks for all the help everyone! I will keep all the advice in mind for future projects. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These lines won't work:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet") 
SQL = "SELECT ID, storeNumber, siteOwner FROM OrderOwners WHERE ID = " & rs("ID")
```

Those lines are failing because you just wiped out `rs("ID")` by setting `rs` in the line above it.

You need to pass in the ID you are trying to retrieve the information for to the SQL query.  Just be careful if this is a public site, as if you are passing the ID via a querystring, you could be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ok, I changed the SQL to `SQL = "SELECT ID, storeNumber, siteOwner FROM OrderOwners WHERE ID = ?"`

Comment: I can't get ID any way I try. When I put a number in that corresponds to an ID in the database, data is pulled just fine. I have no idea what to put after `WHERE ID =` to make this work

Comment: @jlg - are you trying to select a record for a specific ID, or bring back all records?  If you need to bring back a specific record, how is the page getting passed the ID?

Comment: Just a specific ID, there is a page with a dropdown to select multiple records but now they want an extra page that selects one record based on the user that is logged in. I suppose I haven't added anything to the page to get an ID based on the criteria I just mentioned. Ok.....blonde moment. Well now I know what to think of! :) thanks